# having problem set up Firebase Cloud Messaging for ios App

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I wanted to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) for my iOS app. I followed the firebase documentation but I can't seem to get it to work. This is my app delegate file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcmMessageIDKey"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // ...
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([[.banner, .sound]])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // ...
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    
    
}
```

I also set up the app capabilities:
[capability setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF9zk.png)

I also check many times that I have my APNs auth key right.

But when I tried to send a test notification from the firebase notification composer, nothing popped up on my phone. The function `didReceiveRegistrationToken` is working and provides a token, but when I used the token to 'send test message', nothing happened.

I tried to make an empty Xcode project side-by-side with the documentation to see if the issue is with my existing app, but it still didn't work.

Is there anything else that I'm missing here?

Comment: You have a few delegate methods missing.

Comment: @ElTomato Hi, do you mind telling me what delegate methods I need? Or maybe point me to some documentation or tutorial. Thank!